# Computing a Matrix Vector Product in Prolog Simply

Tags: prolog

I'm very new to prolog, specifically, SWI-PL. I've seen several related questions about computing matrix-vector products. It seems that they're all unnecessarily complicated or use libraries. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20619516/3973834) contains a nice first principles implementation of the dot product as:

```
dot([], [], 0).
dot([H1|T1], [H2|T2], Result) :- 
  Prod is H1 * H2,
  dot(T1, T2, Remaining),
  Result is Prod + Remaining.
```

It seems like we could get a nice definition of a matrix vector product (MVP) by applying `dot` to every element of the matrix and every element of the list. Something like:

```
maplist(dot, M, V, R).
```

or

```
maplist(maplist(dot), M, V, R).
```

where M is a matrix (list of lists), v is a vector, and R is the result. however, these consistently give `false`, for values such as:

```
[[2,3],[4,5]],[1,0]
```

what am I missing?

Comment: `v` is *not* a variable, but a *constant*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good catch. It's still returning false though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`maplist` concurrently iterates the three lists. So that means that for a call:

```
maplist(dot, M, V, R)
```

it means that `dot(Mi, Vi, Ri)` (this is "pseudo-code") will hold for all `i`. But this does not match with the types: `dot` expects the three parameters to be *lists*, now the element of a vector `Vi` is a number, not a sublist. If you multiply a matrix `M` with a vector `V`, the `i`-th value of the `R`esult is: `dot(Mi, V, Ri)`. Since a dot product is *commutative*, we can swap the operands, so `dot(V, Mi, Ri)` holds as well.

So that means that we can define the matrix-vector product as:

```
matvecprod(M, V, R) :-
    maplist(dot(V), M, R).
```

For example:

```
?- matvecprod([[1,-1,2], [0,-3,1]], [2,1,0], R).
R = [1, -3].
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer. The example you give is generating an error for some reason:
`ERROR: Type error: "atom" expected, found "dot([2,1,0])" (a compound)'

Comment: @EvanRosica: I can not reproduce this locally. What distribution+version of Prolog do you use?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems the error was on my end. Something else in my database file was causing a conflict. You might want to change the name of the example to match your definition.